# curl command json response value without jq

Tags: json, shell, curl

my curl command returns a json response

```
{"token":"abcd"}
```

how do I get the token value into a variable in the shellscript? 
i can not use jq something most posts have suggested in the past. The pattern of this response is also set (there will be only 1 key-value pair), so if this response can in anyway be converted to a string then using substring could be a option.

Answer (score -1):

I found this [blog](http://swaeku.github.io/blog/2013/12/05/approximative-json-parsing-in-shell-scripts/), did exactly what I want. Works wonder.